# Function causing the loop display posting more (empty)

Tags: custom-post-types, php, mysql, html5

By using the function:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_types_to_loop' );

function add_custom_post_types_to_loop( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'property' );
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

I encounter the following problem (post overflow):

[image]

My code loop is as follows:

```
<?php 
    global $post, $query_string, $SMTheme;

    $i=1;

    if (have_posts() ) :  

    if (!isset($_GET['ajaxpage'])) {?>
 <div class='articles'>
    <?php }
    while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    ?>
        <!-- div one-post -->
        <div class='one-post'>
        <!-- div post -->
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class("post-caption"); ?>>


            <?php /* Título */

            if (!is_single()&&!is_page()) { ?>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( $SMTheme->_( 'permalink' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" class='post_ttl'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <?php } /* Fim Título */ ?>

            <!-- Paragrafo --><p <?php /* Edição de post e data */if(is_page()) echo 'style="display:none"' ?>><?php if (!is_page()) {?><span class='post-date'><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span> <img alt="" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/smt/category.png"><?php echo $SMTheme->_('before-category'); ?><?php the_category(',&nbsp;'); }?>
            <?php if(comments_open( get_the_ID() ))  {
                    ?><img alt="" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/smt/comments.png"> | <span class="meta_comments"><?php comments_popup_link( $SMTheme->_( 'noresponses' ), $SMTheme->_( 'oneresponse' ), $SMTheme->_( 'multiresponse' ) ); ?></span><?php
                }
                ?><?php edit_post_link( $SMTheme->_( 'edit' ), '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
                <span>
                    <?php if(function_exists('the_views')) { the_views(); } ?>
                </span>
                </p><?php /* Fim Edição de post e data */ ?><!-- Fim Paragrafo -->

        </div> <!-- Fim div post -->

        <!-- post-body -->
        <div class='post-body'>
            <?php
                /* Miniatura */
                if(has_post_thumbnail())  {
                    ?><?php if (!is_single()) { ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( $SMTheme->_( 'permalink' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(
                        'post-thumbnail',
                        array("class" => $SMTheme->get( 'layout','imgpos' ) . " featured_image")
                    ); ?></a><?php } else { ?>
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(
                        array(278, 173),
                        array("class" => $SMTheme->get( 'layout','imgpos' ) . " featured_image")
                    ); ?>
                    <?php }
                }
                /*  Fim Miniatura */

                /* Leia Mais */
                if (!is_single()&&!is_page()) {
                    if ( ! post_password_required() ) { the_excerpt('echo=1'); } else the_content('');
                    ?><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' class='readmore'><?php echo $SMTheme->_( 'readmore' ); ?></a><?php
                } else {
                    the_content('');

                }

                /* Fim Leia Mais */
            ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>
        </div><!-- Fim div post-body -->
        </div><!-- Fim div one-post -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php if (!isset($_GET['ajaxpage'])) {?>
 </div><!-- Fim div articles -->
    <?php } ?>


<?php endif;
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Any tips for this to be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening if you remove the `pre_get_posts` hook?

Either way, you can try wrapping the code in a conditional.

```
while (have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
if ( 0 < intval( the_ID() ) {
...
}
endwhile;
```

This is not quite as good as limiting the number of records returned by the query but it doesn't hurt to validate as you go along anyways.